# SSIS package falied c#

Tags: c#, ssis

These are the errors that I encountered when calling a SSIS package on asp.net

> SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. An OLE DB error has occurred. Error
>   code: 0x80004005. An OLE DB record is available. Source: "Microsoft
>   Access Database Engine" Hresult: 0x80004005 Description: "Could not
>   find installable ISAM.". SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER. The
>   AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "Excel
>   Connection Manager" failed with error code 0xC0202009. There may be
>   error messages posted before this with more information on why the
>   AcquireConnection method call failed. component "Excel Source" (1)
>   failed validation and returned error code 0xC020801C. One or more
>   component failed validation.

Any recommended solutions to this?

Comment: this is a pretty generic error that means your Excel connection string is wrong; you need to at least explain how you're connecting to Excel in detail so we can see what's going on.

Comment: (also, in case it wasn't obvious, you need Excel *installed* on the machine running the SSIS package...)

Comment: package.Connections["SourceConnectionExcel"].ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filePath1 + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1'";

Comment: this is the connection string that im using to connect

Comment: please help! stuck at this for days

Comment: That's what you get for using SSIS.

Answer (score 0):

This may be of some help:

*Have you set DelayValidation Property of Data Flow Tasks to TRUE in your SSIS package? For more information about the error, please see the following article:*

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ramoji/archive/2009/03/10/the-acquireconnection-method-call-to-the-connection-manager-failed-with-error-code-0xc0202009.aspx

Comment: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E4D. An OLE DB record is available. Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0" Hresult: 0x80040E4D Description: "Login failed for user 'user'.". SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER. The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "DestinationConnectionOLEDB" failed with error code 0xC0202009. There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed. component "Destination -

Comment: I found that if I set DelayValidation=True for BOTH the data flow task AND the Excel connection manager, I get  consistent successful runs.